# tooltip for dynamically generated @html.dropdown control in mvc4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on web project in `MVC 4` with `Razor` and `C#`. I have used `@Html.DropDownList` that display items dynamically.

I want to set `ToolTip` for every item of `@Html.DropDownList`. This is my code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Config_Industry", ViewBag.Industry as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Please Choose Item", new
{
    @class = "drpDownCustomEngineered",
    @style = "width: 258px;"                                               
})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) there is no such an opportunity for `DropDownList`, but

you can use `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
  $("#CategoryID option").each(function() {
      $(this).attr({'title': $(this).html()});
    });
  });
</script>
```